# BigCommerce Webhook Not Triggering

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I created a webhook in BigCommerce using following code:

```
use Bigcommerce\Api\Connection;

$connection = new Connection();

$connection->setCipher('RC4-SHA');
$connection->verifyPeer(false);
$connection->addHeader('X-Auth-Client', $clientId);
$connection->addHeader('X-Auth-Token', $token);

$response = $connection->post('https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/' . $hash . '/v2/hooks', json_encode(array(
    'scope'=>'store/order/created',
    'destination'=>'https://bigcommerce.example.com/order'
)));
```

I got the response as following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 568
    [client_id] => lms4gxejy2xw2bia7w30v3bal1sz5yz
    [store_hash] => xxxxxx
    [scope] => store/order/created
    [destination] => https://bigcommerce.example.com/order
    [headers] => 
    [is_active] => 1
    [created_at] => 1403762563
    [updated_at] => 1403762563
)
```

However, I never got any callbacks to https://bigcommerce.example.com/order from BigCommerce whenever order is placed. The website is having a valid SSL. Any ideas?

Comment: First, can you please be clear about whether or not you have changed the destination from your original code to what you posted here?

Comment: Yes, I changed the destination due privacy issue.

Comment: Same here. Using OAuth, hook successfully created and active, valid ssl certificate, but no callbacks. It seems to be a common issue.

Comment: Anyone having any luck here? I have had the same issue for weeks and don't understand what's causing the webhooks not to fire. I used OAuth to successfully create the hook and my destination is using a valid SSL Cert from a CA. I'm getting absolutely no response from BigCommerce support about the issue.  I've had a ticket open with them for over two weeks now and every time I call to check the status they just give me the run around. Very very frustrating.

Comment: I have contacted BigCommerce and waiting replies from them. It seems like the issue is from their side.

Comment: I also checked traffic to my server via ```iftop``` linux utility, no incoming traffit to my 443 port. So it's not error on my server. Try to check if thereis traffic to 443 port on your server.

Comment: @SeiKan please let us know about their reply

Comment: @SeiKan, have you had any luck here? I also have not received a response from BigCommerce regarding the same issue. There are being extremely unresponsive about this and I'm not sure why. I've had an outstanding case with them about this issue for over a month.

Comment: Still no replies from BigCommerce. I will keep you all updated once I got anything back.

Answer (score 1):

ClientID & ClientSecret?

I assume you are using the standard (now old) authentication and not using OAuth for your integration? OAuth is required for webhooks (see the documentation).

I know you have HTTPS but you also need a valid cert from a trusted CA. (Only mentioned as it is commonly an issue)

Comment: Edited my post. It's oAuth ith token. The webhook is created successfully with a proper Id generated (Refer to the response I got).

Comment: The HTTPS is a trusted CA as well. However, I can't see any callbacks from BigCommerce in my application log nor Apache log.

Comment: You not using OAuth though? This is required, you can't use basic authentication. See documentation here https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started it states `Before your app can create a webhook, you require an OAuth access token for each store on which you wish to register hooks.`

Comment: If @SeiKan successfully created webhook this means he uses OAuth. So the problem to my mind is on the BigCommerce side. I wish they give us some kind of logs or something to debug. I have the same problem by the way. I've created webhook but see no requests to registered URL.